# how to evaluate rasa nlu model

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, spacy, rasa-nlu

Got error while evaluating the rasa nlu model using run_evaluation module in kaggle notebook as:

```
TypeError: classification_report() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output_dict'



from rasa_nlu.evaluate import run_evaluation

run_evaluation("nlu.md", model_directory)
expected output:


INFO:rasa_nlu.evaluate:There were some nlu intent classification errors. Use `--verbose` to show them in the log.
INFO:rasa_nlu.evaluate:Model prediction errors saved to errors.json.
INFO:rasa_nlu.evaluate:Confusion matrix, without normalization: 
[[10  1  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0 13  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 10  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  5  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  6  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0 15  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0 25]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it has to do with your used scikit-learn version (https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/1742). Please try to install `scikit-learn` `0.20.2` or even better upgrade to Rasa `1.x` by doing `pip install rasa`.

Answer (score 0):

The evaluate function is now called test. Try this:

from rasa_nlu.test import run_evaluation

Reference from :
https://forum.rasa.com/t/run-evaluation-function-can-not-be-imported/9258